How to collect all leaf subclasses of a parent class in Python?
Given a base class named ParentClass, how can I find all leaf subclasses of it? For example, if I have:
class ParentClass:
    pass

class SubClass1(ParentClass):
    pass

class SubClass2(ParentClass):
    pass

class SubClass3(ParentClass):
    pass

class SubClass4(SubClass2):
    pass

class SubClass5(SubClass2):
    pass

class SubClass6(SubClass2, SubClass3):
    pass

I want a list containing, [SubClass1, SubClass4, SubClass5, SubClass6], and not SubClass2 or SubClass3 as they are not leaves in the inheritance hierarchy.

Something that's a leaf now might not be a leaf later, and vice versa. This is a very finicky, fragile thing to do.

@user2357112, Interesting. Would there be a case where the classes are ones I have defined and imported, and not all have been loaded? In my particular case, the subclasses are cards in a game, so they're all defined in a few modules, and nothing inherits from the cards themselves.

This sounds like it may be an "XY problem" https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem ...it's an unusual thing to need to do, which often means there is a better design that doesn't need you to do it.

Any solution you take from the answers will require your modules to be imported first.

The simpler approach here would be to just require that each concrete Card class (the leaves you are looking for), would set an attribute that should only be set on the concrete cards (like name) - that could be a metaclass property, and register the concrete cards at once (and, at the same time prevent "abstract" subclasses from being instantiated);

@jsbueno, What do you mean by register the concrete cards at once? It is indeed the case already that every card has a name property and none of the intermediate classes do.

there - I made some code that can create a registry of all subclasses which define name  -and won't allow any class that doesn't to be instantiated. In the answer bellow.

Since the problem is that you have an arbitrary hierarchy, and just want the subclassmost to be "concrete" classes, and having a registry for them, maybe requiring, in one of the base classes, that these concrete classes set a class attribute that all concrete implementations should have, but that would not make sense for intermediate classes (I can imagine a card .name attribute, for example).
The usual mechanism of Abstract Base Classes for Python can work for this, with the required attribute overriding a method in the baseclass marked as @abstractmethod and an __init_subclass__ method in the same base can then add that class to a registry with your desired leave classes (And even check if a class marked as "leave" by setting name had been further subclassed, raising an error)
class Base(ABC):
    # All concrete classes must set a "name" attribute
    name = abstractmethod(lambda:None)
    _card_registry = set()
    def __init_subclass__(cls, *args, **kw):
        if cls.name is not __class__.name:  # subclass overwrote ".name"
            # optional - check if no other superclass of cls, other than this one,  set name:
            for supercls in cls.__mro__[1:]:
                if supercls is __class__:
                    break
                if getattr(supercls, "name") is not __class__.name:
                    raise TypeError(f"{supercls.__name__} class setting ´.name´ was further subclassed")
            __class__._card_registry.add(cls)
        super().__init_subclass__(*args, **kw)

And after importing all your modules, Base._card_registry would contain all classes that interest you.

Now, the literal answer for getting all the leafmost subclasses, although not the best pattern in this specific case:
Python will allow one to retrieve class' direct subclasses with the .__subclasses__ method. A simple code to retrieve all current leave classes could be:
def getleaves(cls, leaves=None):
    if leaves is None: leaves=set()
    if subclasses:=cls.__subclasses__():
        for subclass in subclasses:
            getleaves(subclass, leaves)
    else:
        leaves.add(cls)
    return leaves


I accepted this, though I suppose this is helping me solve my problem more than directly answering the question.

yes - for sake of completeness, I added some code that does the same here.

This function starts with the parent class and iterates through its subclasses, appending the unique leaf subclasses to a list.
def leaf_subclasses(parent_class):
    leaves = []
    subclasses = [parent_class]
    while subclasses:
        next_subclasses = []
        for cls in subclasses:
            if cls.__subclasses__():
                next_subclasses.extend(cls.__subclasses__())
            elif cls not in leaves:
                leaves.append(cls)
        subclasses = next_subclasses
    return leaves

print(leaf_subclasses(ParentClass))


This only works if the entire class hierarchy has already been loaded, which will frequently not be the case.

If one wants to lazily calculate subclasses, the only thing that can possibly be done is to have some code like this as a property, either as a classmethod, or in the metaclass.
Anyway, lone can´t get a reference to a class that has not being imported yet - simply because it doesn´t exist! One simply could not write some code that would trigger "all possible imports in the universe", so that it could find all possible leave classes

@user2357112 : in other words, code like this is the only code that makes sense. "possible classes that will become leaves in the future when their modules are imported" are not Python objects.
